# why is my json returning nil

Tags: json, swift

```
    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://app.avatejaratsaba1.com/api/Values/GetPriceList?paymentType=1&goodType=102")
    var request = URLRequest(url: myUrl!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET" // compose a query string
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
    {
        (data : Data? , response : URLResponse? , error : Error?) in

        self.removeActivtyIndicator(activityIndicator: MyActivityIndicator)

        if error != nil
        {
            self.DisplayMessage(UserMessage: "2Could not successfully perform this request , please try again later.")
            print("error = \(String(describing : error))")

        }
        // let's convert response sent from a server side code to a NSDictionary object:

        do { let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            if let parseJSON = json
            {
```

I have the exact code in another viewcontroller with another url and it works properly !!! it works properly in Postman!!

and i'm coding swift

UPDATED::::

```
do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String:Any]] {
                var goodNameArray = [String].self
                for i in 0..<json.count{
                    guard let goodName = json[i]["goodName"] as? String else{return}
                    Global.GlobalVariable.GoodName = goodNameArray.append(goodName)
                }
                print("GoodNames: \(goodNameArray)")
            }
        } catch let parseError {
            print("parsing error: \(parseError)")
            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("raw response: \(String(describing: responseString))")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

and the error it returns is :

> Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(String)'

global var code:::::

```
class Global: UIViewController
```

{

```
struct GlobalVariable
{
    static var companyName = "Company"
    static var bigName = ((0) , (""))
    static var names  = ["Loading..." , ""]
////////////
    static var AgentInfo = "agentinfo"
////////////
    static var genaral_goodID = 000
    static var GoodName = [String]()
    static var PriceVariableName = "PriceVariableName"
    static var paymentType = "paymentType"
    static var fee = "fee"
    static var exipreDate = "exipreDate"
    static var expireTime = "expireTime"


}
```

}

UPDATED::::::

uitable

```
class secondtable : TableViewController
{

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Global.GlobalVariable.names.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let content = Global.GlobalVariable.GoodName[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = content
        //cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator


        return cell

    }
```

}
here in this par of my code , i'm supposed to populate a table with "goodName"

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include the actual JSON response you're trying to parse. Btw don't use `.mutableContainers` as it has no effect in Swift. Also don't use `NSDictionary`, use `Dictionary<String:Any>` while parsing a JSON Dictionary in Swift.

Comment: my problem is that i receive an empty json! those you mentioned are not my concern yet !!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Well if you receive an empty JSON, then you most definitely have a problem with your url request and/or backend. You should include a screenshot of how your request is set up in Postman and what response you receive. Or simply copy the cURL code Postman generates for that request if you checked that works too.

Comment: Works for me. Nice and fast too. PO data, is it empty or did you get content?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz that is the problem for me!!!! with another url it works on another viewcontroller , but in this viewcontroller it sucks with this specific url

Comment: I repeat, does "data" contain any data or not? Add a line of code to print it out before self.remove and see if you are actually getting data.

Comment: i set some breakpoint to check them and the "json" was nil!

Comment: I repeat, does "data" contain any data or not?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz if you mean servers data, yes! server contain a json object, and if you the json i receive , no! it doesn't contain any data

Comment: The "data" is empty too @MauryMarkowitz

Comment: Ok, then your request is not being served. That is the problem. PO the request in both views and compare them, there IS a difference.

Comment: I copied and pasted the whole code to check side by side , and i changed the url only

Comment: Not related but both headers are pointless for a GET request. Pass just the URL `let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myURL!)` and delete the 4 `request` lines. And the root object of the JSON is an array, not a dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested in bellow way ,it is working for me.The response in `array of dictionaries`. Don't do force unwrap.

```
 func viewDidLoad(){
      downloadDataFromServer { (success, goodNamesArray) in
                if success{
                    print("goodNamesArray: \(goodNamesArray)")
                    print("successfully updated tableview data")
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
    }
func downloadDataFromServer(completionHandler: @escaping(Bool,[String])->()){
     guard let url = URL(string: "http://app.avatejaratsaba1.com/api/Values/GetPriceList?paymentType=1&goodType=102")  else {
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                print("request failed \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            do {
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String:Any]] {
                    var goodNameArray = [String]() 
                    for i in 0..<json.count{
                        guard let goodName = json[i]["goodName"] as? String else{return}
                        self.goodNameArray.append(goodName)
                    }
                    print("GoodNames: \(self.goodNameArray)")
                   Global.GlobalVariable.GoodName = goodNameArray
                }
            } catch let parseError {
                print("parsing error: \(parseError)")
                let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                print("raw response: \(String(describing: responseString))")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: it seem work properly, but i need to add , "   do {
    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String:Any]] {
     print("Json: \(json)")
     Global.GlobalVariable.GoodName = json["goodName"] as! [String:Any]
    }  "  but when i add this code , it fails the compil

Comment: and the intresting part is that when i add that code, it prevent  "        print("Json: \(json)")  " to perform

Comment: Okay, how you want  only one value or all goodNames from array.

Comment: @Am1rFT updated my code, you will get all the goodNames in goodNamesArray.

Comment: in "   for i in 0..<json.count{
                guard let goodName = json[i]["goodName"] as? String else{return}
                self.goodNameArray.append(goodName)
            }
            print("GoodNames: \(self.goodNameArray)")
        }  "   it returns a error which says, " Value of type 'ssTableViewController' has no member 'goodNameArray' " :|

Comment: @Am1rFT add this before  for loop  -  var goodNameArray = [String]()

Comment: i changed the code a bit  and solved that problem(error) but it returned another error!!!    i updated my code , pls check that!!

Comment: i save the goodname in a global variable to be able to use it in multi places?!!!

Comment: @Am1rFT Change the type of Global.GlobalVariable.GoodName to [String]().

Comment: @Am1rFT also show Global.GlobalVariable.GoodName code.

Comment: I updated my code again , my uitble is empty , any suggestion ?? in my main class  i have the code " self.tableview.realoaddata()" too

Comment: @Am1rFT check my updated answer, you have to use completionHandler.

Comment: it still doesn't populate my table !!

Comment: @Am1rFT are you using default cell or custom cell

Comment: i changed nothing ! it should be default

Comment: i just check the code , and found out that " Global.GlobalVariable.GoodName = goodNameArray " is empty , and does not pass any data!!!!! and " Global.GlobalVariable.GoodName " retunrns and empty array " [] "

Comment: @Am1rFT goodNameArray has data ,i am printing  it is in viewDidLoad also .May be the problem with Global class .my suggestion is instead of using your own custom class use Codable class.Or make sure your passing data the Global class correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favour and save some time by reading up on the `Codable` protocol. It will allow you to generate a pretty decent JSON-parser by basically just defining your structure. Using `JSONDecoder.decode` will provide you with much more valuable error information if something goes wrong.

Since your API is currently only providing an empty array using the URL you provide us with it is pretty hard to come up with any meaningful code. You should resort to a simple String-representation of your JSON, at least a minimalized form that shows us all about the structure. That way your question would not depend on the workings of a probably fairly complicated web service.